# Spring boot upgarde issue come. Ibm. disthub2. Impl. Jms. TextMesaageImpl

Tags: spring-boot, performance, ibm-mq, incompatibletypeerror

incompatible types com. ibm. disthub2. impl. jms. TextMessageIpml to jakart.jms.TextMessage facing this issue while doing spring boot upgrade please some help here

Need to help on this on how yo fix it and what is wrong please help

Comment: I guess (!) you update to Spring Boot 3, which requires to change your code to use the Jakarta interfaces. This article might be useful: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/mark-taylor/2024/01/15/mq-and-spring-boot-2-now-end-of-life

Answer (score 0):

You will have an import that looks like:

```
import com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage;
```

that needs to be converted into an import that looks like:

```
import com.ibm.jakarta.jms.JMSTextMessage;
```